# Red asterisk in Xtype :'label'

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I would like to put a red asterisk after a text . Is there a way to add directly css code in the js code? Like the parameter style for example but only for the asterisk.I'm working on Extjs 3.4

Here is the code.

```
{
xtype: 'label',
style: "font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;",
 text: 'Note<span style="color:red">*</span>  If any job applicant is failed,you can find it in the error log.',
// fieldLabel: 'Note<span style="color:red">*</span>: If any job applicant is failed,you can find it in the error log.',
 }
```

,

If i use `fieldLabel`,the complete text printing only on left side.
and span is working for `"fieldLable"` but span is not working for `"text"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `html` instead of `text`.

```js
Ext.onReady(function() {
    new Ext.FormPanel({
    height: 100,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'label',
style: "font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;",
 html: 'Note<span style="color:red">*</span>  If any job applicant is failed,you can find it in the error log.',
    }]
});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/3.4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/3.4.1.1/adapter/ext/ext-base-debug.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/3.4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add panel after label as:

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    forId: 'myFieldId',
    text: 'Note',
},{
    xtype:'panel',
    html:'<span style="color:red;">*</span> If any job applicant is failed,you can find it in the error log.'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution.  Using class and :before.  [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qel)